# jPlayer doesn't play audio file automatically in iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, jplayer, ipod

I am trying to play audio file using jPlayer in iPad. It works fine in Safari on my local PC but when I tried to open it in my iPad it doesn't play audio automatically.

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have to initialize jPlayer on user action in Mobile Safari.

> The first time a media element is played must be initiated by a user gester. ie., The user must click the play button. This affects the operation of a jPlayer("play") in the ready event handler. The browser will ignore the command. jPlayer will simply wait until the user presses the play button.
>   Once the first gesture has been received, JavaScript code is then allowed to do whatever you want with the media element. Note that a jPlayer media player instance uses a audio and a video element. Each require their own gesture.

As a hack, you could possibly add a handler for a touch event on an outer container element (or body) and initialize any jPlayer instances that you want.

Ref: http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-known-issues-event-driven

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean it doesn't play automatically? Because if it does, I don't see what your problem is.

Comment: @C.C. I was trying to get clarification from the OP. He said it 'does play automatically' which means there's no problem, i assume he meant it doesn't play automatically. No big deal, just wanted clarification.

Comment: oic, got it. I just mean that there is no way automatically start it on an iOS device :)

Answer (score -3):

Check if you have entered the correct path for option swfPath.